# Onload time is greater than finish time

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am seeing my onload time is greater than the finish time. As per my knowledge its vice versa. Can anyone explain?
Refer the image

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please put the data from the link into the question, so everybody can see it at a glance. That would improve your odds of getting the question answered

Comment: Do you have Javascript code fetching resources after your page is loaded?

Comment: This is a after Login Page. and this is first part of the page out of 4 parts(redirections).This is where i am seeing onload greater than finish time

Comment: There is no JS. There is just a POST request i.e, ajax request made.